# Send object through HttpWebRequest (REST Service)

Tags: c#, rest, serializable

I have a REST Service that accepts a id in the URL for PUT requests. So far the PUT request looks like this:

```
string url = "http://localhost:3596/WidgetManager.svc/Widgets/" + TextBox3.Text;
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "PUT";

using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
    Label4.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

But I also need to send a Widget object in my request.

```
Widget w = new Widget();
w.Name = "worked!!!";
w.CogCount = 1000;
w.SprocketSize = 2000;
```

I saw a lot of examples on how to send strings. But what about objects like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could serialise it using XML or JSON.
If it is such a small object, you could write your own small method like

```
.toJSON() {
   return '{"Name":"' + this.name + '", "CogCount":' + this.CogCount + ', "SprocketSize":' + this.SprocketSize + '}';
}
//Output: '{"Name":"worked!!!", "CogCount":1000, "SprocketSize":2000}'
```

On the other hand: C# provides powerful (XML) serialisation tools!
This here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1789/Object-Serialization-using-C is only one of many examples.

But if you use PHP or similar, JSON might even be more interesting.